# Tomcat + SSL configuration + Client

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl, https

So, everybody saying different things. Somebody use "keytool", somebody "openssl". Somebody prefer APR Tomcat, somebody's not. 
My application is a backend for mobile applications (Android/IOS), and there will be browser in the future. I'm using REST approach. 
Which is best way to establish SSL connection between server and client with minimal headache for client? Which files do i need? Note that client's list are very wide: Android, IOS, Browser, HttpClient, RestTemplate and so on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate your certificate CN at https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/keytool.htm
2. `keytool -genkey -alias <FQDN> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore <yourKeyStore_name>.jks -dname "CN=FQDN,OU=Dept, O=CompanyName, L=CityName, ST=StateName, C=ISO-CountryCode" && keytool -certreq -alias <FQDN> -file CertificateRequest.csr -keystore <yourKeyStore_name>.jks` && echo Your certificate signing request is in `CertRer.csr`.  Your keystore file is `KeyStoreName.jks`.  Thanks for using the DigiCert keytool CSR helper.
3. `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias <FQDN> -file 1_root_bundle.crt -file 2_<cert>.crt -keystore YourChainStore.jks`
4. List your certificate if it was stored right
   `keytool -keystore YourChainStore.jks -list`
5. Configure your Tomcat Web server
   `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml`